# Jquery find children element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the children element of a div my code looks like this , HTML

```
<div class="section">
    <div id="element">
        <input id="answer" type="hidden"> 
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

what i want is once i click submit it should find the class section and get me the value of hidden field , my js looks like this

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
     answer = $('.section').children('#answer').val();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method instead.

```
$('.section').find('#answer').val();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jQh4q/

It's also worth pointing out that if you're using the ID "answer" in multiple places in your page, your html will not be valid.

I'm assuming this is the case since otherwise you'd be selecting the ID directly and not going in through its parent.

Comment: yup it worked i was using it on the wrong place ,thanks jamie

Comment: See my update also bob. If you're using the id in multiple places you'll want to switch it to a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Each ID should be **unique**.
To retreive the value of #answer you can simply do this:

```
$('#answer').val();
```

Comment: Beat me by 10secs. I am out of votes, but you deserve a +1. Someone upvote this guy. :)

Comment: Always nice to see someone agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var answer = $('#answer').val();
});
```

There is no need for children or such thing, IDs *must* be unique. So, you just select the element by its id directly.